# Consultas en múltiples tablas con laravel +5.5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Necesito hacer consultas en múltiples tablas (más de 6) y en cadena, pero desconozco cual será la forma más fácil y eficiente de traer los datos con laravel, ya que tiene un par de métodos para hacer las consultas y traer las colecciones.

Alguien puede aportar un ejemplo de una consulta extensa? Laravel posee algún método especial para este tipo de consultas?

**Ejemplo// Tablas: a, b, c, d, e, f**

Quiero traer los datos de todas las tablas relacionadas, los datos de a, b, c, d,e,f.

- A está relacionado con B (1,n)
- B con C (1,n)
- C con D  (1,n)
- D con E (1,n)
- E con F (1,n)

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida, necesitas agregar mas detalles a tus tablas, escalrecer que tipo de relación tienen las tablas, si estas construyendo los JOINS o usas las relaciones de eloquent

Comment: El tema no va por los atributos así que lo encuentro innecesario, la idea es abordar el tipo de consultas entre muchas tablas, laravel tiene diversos métodos para hacer consultas como with, join y sentencias crudas entre otros. La idea es que alguien me pueda ejemplificar el mejor método para consultas en muchas tablas ¿Me explico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel posee un ORM llamado Eloquent que puedes usar.

Por ejemplo.

Supongamos que tienes 4 tablas llamadas As , Bs, Cs y Ds
Colocamos la s delante de cada letra para saber que el nombre de la tabla es en plural, es decir, que alberga muchas letras A

Cada una relacionada con la otra en una relación de uno a muchos. Es decir, A tiene muchas Bs y Cada B pertenece a una A. Y así hasta llegar a la D.

Puedes usar Eloquent para crear Modelos/Clases que representen a las tablas. Y con ayuda del `with` aplicar eager loading.

y colocar en tu codigo algo como

```
$a = App\A::with(['bs', 'bs.cs', 'bs.cs.ds'])->get();
```

Esto ejecutará todas las SQL necesarias para tomar la información de todas las relaciones de todos los elementos de la tablas As.
**Creo que usé muchas veces la palabra todas**

Aunque también puedes ignorar el with, pero esto hará que Eloquent aplique el Lazy Loading que quizás te lleve al famoso problema del

> N + 1 queries

al momento de querer realizar un foreach de tu relaciones

```
foreach($a->bs as $b) { 
    foreach($b->cs as $c) { 
        foreach($c->ds as $d) {
        } 
    } 
}
```

En la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) puedes ver más acerca de esto

Comment: Gracias, pero como puedo utilizar el where para traer un registro especifico, como identifico la tabla para poder comparar su propiedad? ya que with trae todos los registros

Comment: Por ejemplo, como puedo hacer que 'bs.cs.ds' atributoX = 40 y 'bs.cs' atributoY = true

Comment: Puedes restringir lo que el Eager Loading cargará con el siguiente ejemplo: `$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}])->get();`

de esta forma puedes colocar `$query->where('atributo', 40)` o si el nombre de la columna esta repetido en varias tablas puedes especificar la tabla colocando `tabla.atributo` o `tabla.tablarelacionada.atributo`. Todo esto es por si necesitas el eager loading. [Más información aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)